# Polymer 0.9 template repeat

Tags: polymer

I was trying to upgrade from Polymer 0.8 to Polymer 0.9.  In Polymer 0.8 the following worked:

```
<template>
    <template is="x-repeat" items="{{array}}">
        <span>{{item.member}}</span>
    </template>
</template>
```

However, this does not appear to work with Polymer 0.9.  What is the new approach that should be used?

Note, Polymer 0.5 used the following:

```
<template>
    <template repeat="{{item in array}}">
        <span>{{item.member}}</span>
    </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x-repeat is getting renamed in 0.9 to dom-repeat. ([source](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1502))

So this should work for you:

```
<template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{array}}">
        <span>{{item.member}}</span>
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you.  It will be nice when the 0.9 documentation is released!  Just trying to update early to get some bug fixes.